# empty value of parameter - php

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
foreach($summary as $machine)
{
    $hostname = $machine['node'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT OS FROM machines WHERE ind='$hostname'");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

    {

        if($row == 'solaris')
        {
            $partition_os = 'export/home';
        }
        else
        {
             $partition_os = '/home';
        }
    }
}
  <partition<?php echo $i; ?>><?php echo $partition_os; ?></partition<?php echo $i; ?>>
```

The output of the query is:(without the `where`)

```
mysql> SELECT OS FROM machines;
+---------+
| OS      |
+---------+
| NULL    |
| solaris |
+---------+
```

My problem is that in my xml (this is for ajax) i see only `/home/` instead of `export/home`.
The `$hostname` supposed to be fine because i use it before.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you expecting exactly one row from your query? It looks like (from your comment on Colin's answer) you're getting two, and the second one (the one that's being used) is empty.

Comment: one row per i..in my case there is 2 i and therefor 2 arrays. i dont know why it's empty but anyway, the first one is solaris but itsn't working.

Comment: If you want to echo an XML element for each row, you'd better bring that piece of code into the loop, as @codaddict and I pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
if($row == 'solaris')
```

With:

```
if($row['OS'] == 'solaris')
```

Comment: @Colin: Quoting: `The type of array that is to be fetched. It's a constant and can take the following values: MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_NUM, and the default value of MYSQL_BOTH`

Comment: @Sarfraz, I just checked that and removed my comment.

Comment: I don't see how its *not* an assoc.

Comment: the default is  MYSQL_BOTH , and its assoc + numeric

Comment: @Ronny: Make sure that your query runs successfully and row contains each fetched row by echoing its values. Also put `or die(mysql_error())` in your mysql_query function to see if it goes through.

Answer (score 2):

[`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) returns an array, you're comparing an array to a String here.

Try with `$row[0] == 'solaris'` to compare.

Comment: Then you should try to print_r your `$row` and see the result.

Comment: i added `print_r($row);` before the `if` and got this :`Array
(   [0] => solaris
    [OS] => solaris
)
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [OS] => 
)
`

Comment: also did `print_r($row['OS']);` after the `if` and got `solaris`

Comment: As you're doing a while loop on your selection, I suppose that there is more than one element, and as the `$partition_os` variable only contains the value of the last element of the selection, I also suppose that the last element is `NULL`. You should check that the query only gets one row.

Answer (score 1):

Try brining your echo statement inside the foreach loop as:

```
foreach($summary as $machine) {

        $hostname = $machine['node'];

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT OS FROM machines WHERE ind='$hostname'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                if($row == 'solaris') {
                        $partition_os = 'export/home';
                } else {
                        $partition_os = '/home';
                }
        }
        echo "<partition$i>".$partition_os."</partition$i>";
}
```

I don't see what `$i` is.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say whether you're missing some `<?php` tags for brevity or what, but it seems that your XML is outside your loop. This means you're only printing it once (after the whole loop is finished), using the last value of `$partition_os` set in the loop.

Based on your comment on another answer (where you did `print_r`), it looks like your query is returning two rows, the 'solaris' one you're looking for, and then an empty one. It's the latter (empty) one that's setting your `$partition_os` value.

(...and both other answers are correct that you need to compare `$row[0]` or `$row['OS']`)